# Predicting the output of PHP's rand()

Tags: security, random

I've read in numerous sources that the output of PHP's rand() is predictable as its a PRNG, and I mostly accept that as fact simply because I've seen it in so many places.

I'm interested in a proof-of-concept: how would I go about predicting the output of rand()? From reading [this article](http://improved-security.com/wiki/Randomization_%28PHP%29#Why_not_use_rand.28.29_and_mt_rand.28.29.3F) I understand that the random number is a number returned from a list starting at a pointer (the seed) -- but I can't imagine how this is predictable.

Could someone reasonably figure out what random # was generated via rand() at a given moment in time within a few thousand guesses? or even 10,000 guesses? How?

This is coming up because I saw a auth library which uses rand() to produce a token for users who have lost passwords, and I assumed this was a potential security hole. I've since replaced the method with hashing a mixture of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`, the orignal hashed password, and microtime. After doing this I realized that if I were on the outside looking in, I'd have no idea how to guess the token even knowing it was a md5 of rand().

Comment: "but I can't imagine how this is predictable"?  You need to read up on "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator first so that you can begin to imagine how it's predictable.  Then you can revise your question to eliminate the astonishment and move to the more practical issues of reverse engineering the PHP rand function source to see how it works.

Comment: "I assumed this was a potential security hole"?  Only if Evil Hacker could get some user's random password, use a rainbow table to undo the MD5 hash to recover the original (pre-hash) value and then guarantee that they made the very next password request.  Theoretically possible, I suppose.  But only if they had a working rainbow table for a random number.

Comment: @S.Lott - its not a matter of a password. The system lets you reset the password and emails you a token which is used in a URL. The token is generated via MD5(rand()). If you can predict the output of rand() you could change anyone's password, without having the hash for the original, or knowing the original.

Comment: @Erik.  Right.  Replace "random password" with "random token" if that helps.  The token can only be abused if someone can unwind the MD5 hash to recover the random number AND assure that they will get the next random number.  Predicting the next rand is only one small part.  Undoing the MD5 is the hard part.

Comment: Note that MD5(rand()) only has the same security as rand(). It's practical to build a lookup table of MD5(rand()) -> rand() for the very limited set of numbers involved. With rand()'s limited domain you could try simple brute force unless there is a mechanism in place preventing repeated attempts.

Comment: @S.Lott no, actually undoing an MD5 hash is an easy part -- I can calculate ~ 150 million hashes per second on my home computer with software made to use the GPU. Reversing the MD5 of a number within a limited range is trivial.

Comment: @MZB: Very limited?  48-bit seeds don't seem limited to me.  That seems to only take 521 hours, so I suppose it's breakable.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The ability to guess the next value from `rand` is tied to being able to determine what `srand` was called with.  In particular, **seeding `srand` with a predetermined number results in predictable output**!  From the PHP interactive prompt:

```
[charles@charles-workstation ~]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > srand(1024);
php > echo rand(1, 100);
97
php > echo rand(1, 100);
97
php > echo rand(1, 100);
39
php > echo rand(1, 100);
77
php > echo rand(1, 100);
93
php > srand(1024);
php > echo rand(1, 100);
97
php > echo rand(1, 100);
97
php > echo rand(1, 100);
39
php > echo rand(1, 100);
77
php > echo rand(1, 100);
93
php >
```

This isn't just some fluke.  Most PHP versions<sup>*</sup> on most platforms<sup>**</sup> will generate the sequence 97, 97, 39, 77, 93 when `srand`'d with 1024.

To be clear, this isn't a problem with PHP, this is a problem with the implementation of `rand` itself.  The same problem appears in other languages that use the same (or a similar) implementation, including Perl.

The trick is that any sane version of PHP will have pre-seeded `srand` with an "unknown" value.  Oh, but it isn't *really* unknown.  From `ext/standard/php_rand.h`:

```c
#define GENERATE_SEED() (((long) (time(0) * getpid())) ^ ((long) (1000000.0 * php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C))))
```

So, it's some math with `time()`, the PID, and the result of `php_combined_lcg`, which is defined in `ext/standard/lcg.c`.  I'm not going to c&p here, as, well, my eyes glazed over and I decided to stop hunting.

A bit of Googling shows that [other areas of PHP don't have the best randomness generation properties](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Mar/519), and calls to `php_combined_lcg` stand out here, especially this bit of analysis:

> Not only does this function (`gettimeofday`) hand us back a precise server timestamp on a silver platter, it also adds in LCG output if we request "more entropy" (from PHP's `uniqid`).

Yeah [that `uniqid`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).  It seems that the value of `php_combined_lcg` is what we see when we look at the resulting hex digits after calling `uniqid` with the second argument set to a true value.

Now, where were we?

Oh yes.  `srand`.

So, if the code you're trying to predict random values from *doesn't* call `srand`, you're going to need to determine the value provided by `php_combined_lcg`, which you can get (indirectly?) through a call to `uniqid`.  With that value in hand, it's *feasible* to brute-force the rest of the value -- `time()`, the PID and some math.  The linked security issue is about breaking sessions, but the same technique would work here.  Again, from the article:

> Here's a summary of the attack steps outlined above:
>
> - wait for the server to reboot
> - fetch a uniqid value
> - brute force the RNG seed from this
> - poll the online status to wait for target to appear
> - interleave status polls with uniqid polls to keep track of current server time and RNG value
> - brute force session ID against server using the time and RNG value interval established in polling

Just replace that last step as required.

(This security issue was reported in an earlier PHP version (5.3.2) than we have currently (5.3.6), so it's possible that the behavior of `uniqid` and/or `php_combined_lcg` has changed, so this *specific* technique might not be workable any longer.  YMMV.)

On the other hand, if the code you're trying to product *calls `srand` manually*, then unless they're using something many times better than the result of `php_combined_lcg`, you're probably going to have a much *easier* time guessing the value and seeding your local generator with the right number.  Most people that would manually call `srand` also wouldn't realize how horrible of an idea this is, and thus aren't likely to use better values.

It's worth noting that `mt_rand` is also afflicted by the same problem.  Seeding `mt_srand` with a known value will also produce predictable results.  Basing your entropy off of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is probably a safer bet.

**tl;dr:** For best results, don't seed the PHP random number generator, and for goodness' sake, don't expose `uniqid` to users.  Doing either or both of these may cause your random numbers to be more guessable.

---

### Update for PHP 7:

PHP 7.0 introduces [`random_bytes`](http://php.net/random_bytes) and [`random_int`](http://php.net/random_int) as core functions.  They use the underlying system's CSPRNG implementation, making them free from the problems that a seeded random number generator has.  They're effectively similar to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`, only without needing an extension to be installed.  [A polyfill is available for PHP5](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

---

*: The [Suhosin security patch](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) changes the behavior of `rand` and `mt_rand` such that they always re-seed with every call.  Suhosin is provided by a third party.  Some Linux distributions include it in their official PHP packages by default, while others make it an option, and others ignore it entirely.

**: Depending on the platform and the underlying library calls being used, different sequences will be generated than documented here, but the results should still be repeatable unless the Suhosin patch is used.

Comment: Thanks Charles -- between your answer and reading the link on linear congruence generator from Tangurena I feel I have a better grasp on it. I already "knew" that using rand() in this fashion was a bad idea, but know I know *why*.

Comment: Wow, props for a thorough well spelled out answer, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

To visually illustrate how non-random the `rand()`function is, here is an image where all pixels are made of "random" red, green and blue values:

[image: Random RGB values]

There normally shouldn't be any pattern in the images.

I've tried calling `srand()` with different values, it doesn't change how predictable this function is.

Note that both aren't cryptographically secure and produce predictable results.

Answer (score 7):

> *the output of PHP's rand() is predictable as its a PRNG*

It is a [linear congruence generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). That means you have a function that is effectively: `NEW_NUMBER = (A * OLD_NUMBER + B) MOD C`. If you chart NEW_NUMBER vs OLD_NUMBER you will start to see diagonal lines. Some of the notes on [PHP's RAND documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) give examples of how to do so.

> *This is coming up because I saw a auth library which uses rand() to produce a token for users who have lost passwords, and I assumed this was a potential security hole.*

On a windows machine, the max value of RAND is 2^15. This gives the attacker only 32,768 possibilities to check.

> *Could someone reasonably figure out what random # was generated via rand() at a given moment in time within a few thousand guesses? or even 10,000 guesses? How?*

While [this article](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/616221/How-We-Learned-to-Cheat-at-Online-Poker-A-Study-in-Software-Security.htm) isn't exactly the one you are looking for, it shows how some researchers took an existing implementation of a random number generator and used it to make money on Texas Holdem. There are 52! possible shuffled decks, but the implementation used a 32-bit random number generator (which is the max number out of mt_getrandmax on a windows machine), and seeded it with the time in milliseconds since midnight. This reduced the number of possible shuffled decks from about 2^226 to about 2^27 making it possible to search in real time and know what deck has been dealt.

> *After doing this I realized that if I were on the outside looking in, I'd have no idea how to guess the token even knowing it was a md5 of rand().*

I'd recommend using something in the [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family as the feds consider md5 broken. Some folks use google to decrypt md5 hashes because they are so common. Just hash something then throw the hash into a google search - basically google has become a giant [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Answer (score 1):

It is really more accurate to say that given a randomly generated number, the next one is relatively predictable. There are only so many numbers it can be. But that doesn't mean that you could guess it, more that you could write a program that does, pretty quickly.

Comment: I think the next number is entirely deterministic.  Not "relatively" but absolutely.  The issue with pseudo-random number generators is that a sequence will pass statistical tests.  Two adjacent numbers, while totally deterministic, will have may statistical properties in common with actual random numbers.

Comment: The next number is entirely deterministic. That's what the "pseudo" in pseudo-random number generator means. On the other hand, the information needed to determine that next number is next-to-impossible to acquire in practice.

Comment: @S.Lott - I was under the impression that a number could appear multiple times in the 2^32 possible outputs and that each time it appears may be followed by a different number. But given a seed of X, returning a result of Y, the next result will always be the same. Thus, in practice, there might be a handful of numbers that follow Y. I may be wrong though; it's a long time since I really looked at PRNGs.